# Wifi has connection issues

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a Netgear JNR1010 router. When I use the Wifi connection without my PC plugged into the router's LAN port everything is fine . But when I have my PC plugged in I frequently encounter problems. No Internet connection. Not even access to the router's control panel. 
Could this possibly be a problem with the cable used to connect my PC to the router? Or is it just a router problem?

UPDATE: That's everyone for your help!
I now have my PC connected directly to the modem and everything looks smooth. So the only explanation is that my PC's ethernet port is faulty.

Comment: When you are having trouble, can you verify a network connection is active? What OS are you using? Have you tried another cable to rule it out?

Answer (score 1):

My first inclination is that your PC is causing some kind of disruption to other devices on the network.

**1**
My best guess for possible causes would include some kind of IP address conflict through DHCP.  Is your PC, that is plugged in, have all of its network settings statically set? If so, it's possible that your router is assigning a DHCP lease and the conflict is being treated poorly.

**2**
Have you changed the settings on this router in any way or is this the factory settings? Sometimes small settings changes can cause problems if you start to mess with how it treats bridging/lan/vlans/etc. A good place to start is to backup your current configuration to a file and then reset it to factory defaults. If that fixes your problem, then you had bad settings.

**3**
As far as accessing your router control panel from WiFi, this option is turned off in some router configurations and has to be manually turned on to allow this. Verify that this is not the case. NOTE: This is not enabling WAN configuration. Just WiFi.

**4**
Does your router pull all of its data from the WAN through DHCP or are you statically setting up things like DNS/Default forwarding route? If your router doesn't have all the information then it is tough for your DHCP clients to pull it.

Comment: Right now I can only comment on 3: Access to the router control panel is most definitely not turned off because when everything is working well I always have access to the control panel.

Answer (score 1):

.Hi Jasjeev!

The ethernet cable that you're using might be an issue, but it's only one of the possible reasons why there's no connection when the computer is directly connected to the router. Other reasons that I have in mind are Ethernet port issue, Wireless connection, and TCP/IP configuration.

Here's what I'll do..

I'll turn off first the wifi switch, bypass the router then try to go online, if it works, there's no issue on the cable or the computer's port. If there's no connection, verify the Local Area Connection, it should be Enabled. Then verify the IP Address if it's Valid, if not, go to Local Area Connection window and choose repair/diagnose the problem. If repair completes successfully, attempt to go online. If repair fails, verify TCP/IP settings are correct. If there are changes made, reboot the computer and try to go online. If no access still, check Device Manager and make sure that the Network Adapter has no error, if there is, you need to contact a technician or the computer's manufacturer. If there's no error on the Network Adapter, run the ping command. If ping result is okay, the connection is just there and attempt to go online. If ping fails for the Domain but not on the IP address, it's a DNS issue and needs to hard code it manually or just run release/renew the IP address and restart the computer. If still there's no access, replace the cord and try to go online. If everything fails, consult a local technician or computer's manufacturer.

Thanks!

~kryte

Answer (score 1):

You might clarify whether only the plugged in PC has issues or whether other devices on the network also have issues.

I'm reading it as the plugged in PC and would suggest trying another cable and/or port on the router.  Make sure you ethernet interface on the PC is enabled, has an IP address (on Windows open the command-line and enter ipconfig (/all for more info)). I'm assuming you're using DHCP coming from the router and this is checking that.

If you have an IP then can you ping the router (IP listed as the Default gateway under ipconfig /all)?

If you can ping the router can you ping the DNS server listed in ipconfig /all?

If you can ping the DNS server, or even if you can't, can you ping www.google.com and see it ping an IP?